# Minha tag <img> não responde a minhas configurações do css

Tags: html, css, img

Eu estava tentando aprender HTML, até que a minha imagem não respondia com meu CSS:

```
img#imagens1{
    height: 19.92;
    width: 19.92; 
}
```

Sendo que a imagem estava respondendo até uns cinco minutos atrás:

```
<img src="IconTwiter.png"id="imagens1">
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: falta a unidade 19,92 o que?

Comment: não entendi o que você quis dizer

Comment: uma unidade de medida do css pode ser `19.92px`

Comment: ta bom,deixa eu ver se funciona desse jeito

Comment: mas acredito que para esses numeros sejam outras unidades CSS: em, px, pt, cm, in…

Comment: o negocio de px fez dar certo,obrigado cara

Comment: Unidades de CSS moderno: rem, vh, vw, vmin, vmax, ex, ch ...

Comment: nunca ouvi falar dessas medidas ,mas ok

Comment: http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/unidades-css-rem-vh-vw-vmin-vmax-ex-ch/

Comment: Uma dica não coloque `img#imagens1` visto que o `id` referencia somente a um úníco elemento no documento.

Comment: pois é, basta #imagens1

Comment: ok,vou considerar isso :)

Comment: vai economizar 3 letras, código mais leve hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você quer passar um tamanho no CSS você precisa indicar em qual medida quer usar, como o amigo falou na resposta de cima, temos a medida "px" que significa pixel. Podemos usasr outras como, "cm", "mm", "pt" etc... algumas responsivas (mudam de tamanho de acordo com o tamanho da tela) como "%" e "fr".

Como você está aprendendo, experimente usar cada um e ver como eles se comportam na sua pagina.

Ex:

```
#imagens1{
    height: 10%;
    width: 10%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que não se passe apenas de uma falta de medida, tente colocar dessa forma

```
#imagens1{
    height: 19.92px;
    width: 19.92px; 
}
```